# control margin of first element of every line

Tags: css

I have this structure of tags that now have margin-left to each one,how can I control so that first element of every first line will not have margin left so it will stick to the left? (for the first element I give margin-left:0px; but how can I do it for the first element of every line?)

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just use Margin-Right on each one?

Comment: .tagContainer:first-child:first-line
{ 
    margin-left:0px;
}

Comment: yes,margin-right is working :),thank you

Answer (score 4):

use `margin-right` would solve your issue

Example :

http://jsfiddle.net/7n5Ww/

Answer (score 2):

rather than providing margin-left, use margin-right property. you won't need to be worried about any line thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

if you have structure like this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

in css you need to do this

```
.wrapper {
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.wrapper div {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

if your element have 10px margin to the left, wrapper must to have negativ margin same like left margin on inner div. This work fine on all browser include ie7+

you can see example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/n3RgW/1

Answer (score 0):

```
li:first-child{
    margin-left: 0px;
}

ul li{
    margin-left: 10px; // change this margin size as you like
}
```

Try this. It will work

Comment: It's what eyal halperin did. But what about the second line in your code ?

Comment: the second line is just the rest of li

Comment: Yep, and the first LI of the second line would be impacted by the margin-left:10px, and will not be aligned with the very first LI...